# How to count related objects

Tags: python, django

I am trying for a model to count related items and save that number into a interger field however it returns an error message:

> TypeError: default_order() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'

Is there a better way to solve this problem and save the number of existing items related to a "level" field? Below is what I intend to be my code:

```
def default_order(obj):
 n = Schedules.objects.filter(level=obj.level).count()
    return n

class Schedules(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Levels,related_name='levels',blank=False,null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=default_order)
```

Comment: You can not use a parameter here. Question looks more, why do you need this? What is the use of `order`?

Comment: That simply not how you would do this.  You don't add a field to every record that has the count of records.  You do your counting outside of the model.

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to evaluate this. The reason is that as long as a record is added, I required to keep that in records ("order field") so they are showed as sorted as changed as required, but user should easily read it and make changes as required, (I tried using the id, but eventually it will be hard to read as more records are added for different levels). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to simplify things by complicating the problem, I solved it by adding below expression in the views while saving in a single new record or when iterating a xls for creating a bunch of records.

```
sequence=Schedules.objects.filter(level=request.user.user_details.level).count() + 1
```

Thank you all.